# Going back from 'Waiting for upload' to ' Ready to upload binary' while publishing app on appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Is there any way to get back from 'Waiting for upload' to 'Ready to upload binary'? I forgot to add in-apps and cannot add them in this state?

I thought of uploading binary and rejecting it, but i'm not sure what's the flow then and if is the correct way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply reject your binary and that will do the trick.
nevertheless, your question is not programming related, nevertheless here is your answer

Comment: No, XCode cant' upload it, so nothing to reject. SO how to get back from "Ready to upload..."?